# Some of the variables will not work in the main method

Tags: java

I want to make an app that identifies your BAC levels but I do not understand why the values do not save alcc and Raw.
I have my methods that calculate these variables and have return statements but for some reason when trying to compile it, I get the "cannot find symbol" error.
Thank you for letting me know what I did wrong, or what I should do.

The errors are the following (both of them are at the same line):

```
AlcoholTester.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    double bac = (alcc/Raw)*100;
```

Code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Option (1) is a shot of liquor. \nOption (2) is a beer. \n Option (3) is a glass of wine. \n");
int temp = s.nextInt();

if(temp == 1){
double alcc = AlcGrams(42.5,40);
}
else if(temp == 2){
    double alcc = AlcGrams(340,5);
}
else if(temp == 3){
    double alcc = AlcGrams(141.7,12);

}
else{
    double alcc = 0;
}


Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds(lbs): ");
double w = sc.nextDouble();


double weight = w * 453.592;



Scanner sce = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your gender: (1)-Male  (2)-Female");
int sexId = sce.nextInt();

if(sexId == 1){
    String sex = "male";
    double Raw = RawNumb(weight,sex);
}
else if(sexId == 2){
    String sex = "female";
    double Raw = RawNumb(weight,sex);
}

double bac = (alcc/Raw)*100; //Here is where the errors take place, one of them shows to alcc and the other to Raw.


Scanner nem = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("When was your last drink? (In hours)");
double hour = nem.nextDouble();


double temporar = bac - hour;
double allc = temporar;
System.out.println("Your alcohol percentage is: " + allc);
```

Comment: Please post the **complete** error message, and indicate which line that is in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two variables are declared in block scope, which means that each time you say `double alcc`, it's only usable within the curly braces in which it is declared. When you attempt to use it outside those blocks, the compiler is telling you correctly that it isn't in scope. You need to declare those variables outside of the `if` blocks. Also, you need to initialize `Raw` because not all code paths assign it a value. As an aside, watch out for the possiblity that your `RawNumb` method returns zero.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Option (1) is a shot of liquor. \nOption (2) is a beer. \n Option (3) is a glass of wine. \n");
    int temp = s.nextInt();

    double alcc;
    double Raw = 0.0;

    if(temp == 1){
        alcc = AlcGrams(42.5,40);
    }
    else if(temp == 2){
            alcc = AlcGrams(340,5);
    }
    else if(temp == 3){
            alcc = AlcGrams(141.7,12);

    }
    else{
        alcc = 0;
    }


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your weight in pounds(lbs): ");
    double w = sc.nextDouble();


    double weight = w * 453.592;

    Scanner sce = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your gender: (1)-Male  (2)-Female");
    int sexId = sce.nextInt();

    if(sexId == 1){
        String sex = "male";
        Raw = RawNumb(weight,sex);
    }
    else if(sexId == 2){
        String sex = "female";
        Raw = RawNumb(weight,sex);
    }

    double bac = (alcc/Raw)*100;


    Scanner nem = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("When was your last drink? (In hours)");
    double hour = nem.nextDouble();


    double temporar = bac - hour;
    double allc = temporar;
    System.out.println("Your alcohol percentage is: " + allc);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Raw` is defined inside two different `if` statements, but you use it outside of the statements. Variable definitions (`double Raw` in this case) only are good for their scope. Before `if(sexId == 1)` just put the line `double Raw` and remove the `double` from the assignments inside the `if`s.